# updated -link between two tables to get username - mysql / php

Tags: php

**What do I want to do with this?**
Well, I have a **school project**, where we have to make a *fully functional website*, where people can **view lyrics of songs**, **create an account**, **login in the account**, **comment on every lyrics** and **edit the lyrics**.

So I have created a DB called `klyrics`
Inside `klyrics` I have the following tables.

Table `users`

```
CREATE TABLE users (
userId int(8) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
username varchar(100),
email varchar(100),
password varchar(100));
```

Table `lyrics`

```
CREATE TABLE lyrics (
lyricsId int(8) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
artist varchar(100),
song varchar(100),
cover varchar(100),
lyrics varchar(9999),
chartId int(8),
commentId int(8),
FOREIGN KEY (chartId) REFERENCES charts(chartId));
```

Table `charts`

```
CREATE TABLE charts (
chartId int(8) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
cover varchar(100),
artist varchar(100),
song varchar(100));
```

and table `comments`

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
commentId int(8) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
userId int(8),
username varchar(100),
comment varchar(9999),
commentedon DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
FOREIGN KEY (userId) REFERENCES users(userId));
```

---

Right now I want to **create a comment system**, so when I open for example the lyrics of Drake's song I can **only comment on that song**, and when I post the comment, I want to **display the username of the guy who posted and the comment**.

I followed this tutorial to create the [login/register system](https://codewithawa.com/posts/complete-user-registration-system-using-php-and-mysql-database)

**So what have I done so far?**
In my `addcomment.php` I have the following code:

```
<?php
include("connectdb.php");

if(isset($_POST) & !empty($_POST)){
    $comment = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['comment']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION['username']);

    $isql = "INSERT INTO comments (comment, username) VALUES ('$comment', '$username')";
    $ires = mysqli_query($conn, $isql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    if($ires){
        $smsg = "Your Comment Submitted Successfully";
        header('location: index.php');
    }else{
        $fmsg = "Failed to Submit Your Comment";
    }

} ?>
```

**Problem 1:** When I submit my comment,the comment goes into the DB and it looks like this: [image]
There is blank spot under the `username`.

**Problem 2:** Comments are not displaying, this is my code to display the comments.

```
    <?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE commentiD = $id";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ( $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {

?>
        <h1>By: <?php echo $r['username']; ?></h1>
        <h1>Comment: <?php echo $r['comment']; ?></h1>

<?php } ?>


<?php
}
?>
```

**Small UPDATE for Problem 2**
Like I said earlier, I have a few pages with ID, so when you click on `View Lyrics` you go to for ex to `http://localhost/klyrics/lyrics.php?id=2`and I only want to see the comments related to this lyrics.

Comment: This is a nicely written question with a lot of details on the subject and what you have already tried, +1.

Comment: `INSERT INTO comments` not `commentss`

Comment: @AlbertoMoro His table is named `commentss`. Look at the CREATE TABLE in the question.

Comment: @Alberto Moro that was my misspelling, when i wrote the post, already corrected, but thanks :)

Comment: The username must be taken from the `$ _POST` not from the `$ _SESSION`

Comment: For the second problem, change your query to `SELECT * FROM comments`. This will select all the comments from the database and not only the one having the field `commentiD` set to the value of `$id

Comment: @Alberto Moro Yep, I tried with $_POST and still got blank in the DB

Comment: And for your first problem. The query is correct. Are you sure the username is the variable you use ? Have you tried to display it to verify ?

Comment: @Noah Boegli Well I tried, `SELECT * FROM comments` but all the comments get displayed, and I want to display the comments only for that page with that ID, if you know what i mean..

Comment: You are not storing any page-id reference in your comment. You cannot use the `commentID` column for that as it is the primary key of your table, thus each row has a different one. You need to add a column such as `lyricsID` that will store the lyrics page ID and then add a WHERE clause to select based on the data in that column.

Comment: If `$_post['username']` is empty maybe there is some problem in your form that doesn't pass the variables correctly

Comment: Since you are following awa tutorials https://codewithawa.com/posts/creating-a-comment-and-reply-system-php-and-mysql same guy has comment system too.

Comment: **Problem 2:** `$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE commentiD = $id";` You're putting `commentiD` as column, even though the column in the screenshot it's called `commentId`. Theres a lot of typos, and I think you should learn the basics of debugging. Not that this is the problem but you're showing us a query with a variable in it but never show where the variable `id` is set.  You're telling us your session is empty. Show us the code that sets the session.

Comment: for problem 1, try to echo  ` $isql` and see if all variables have the supposed values. then if they, do, open phpmyadmin, and copy paste the echoed string (that is if they have all values displaying) and run from there to see what errors you get.

If at echo you do not see all values then you know what the problem is.

Comment: So reading through it, I think the main issues are

Problem 1 - Add `session_start();` before you call `$_SESSION['username']`.
Problem 2 - Since you have passed the id value through href, you need to collect the data by adding `$id = $_GET['id'];`

Also always make sure you echo out and check variable values as part of debugging.

Comment: As I said in my answer! You can’t display comments belong to lycris or posts like that, why ? Because you don’t have postID Or lyricsId in your comment table, you have to insert postID or lyricsId into comment table, then you can display by postID like this in where clause `$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE postID = $id";` following will only display 1 comment if IDS match `$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE commentiD = $id";`

Answer (score 1):

Creating a comment system Like yours! you need to set username and userid to session on login.php.

And add an extra column into your table named `postid`.

And then insert into database like this:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO comments(postid, userid, username, comment)
                VALUES(:postid, :userid, :username, :comment)");
$stmt->bindParam(':postid', $post_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':userid', $_SESSION['userid'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $_SESSION['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':comment', $comment, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

**Attention** `commentid` is autoincrement and `TIMESTAMP 0 ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` no need to add date.

You can use left join or join to get info about post and users from another table etc... like following:

```
SELECT * FROM comments
        JOIN users ON comments.userid = users.userid
        AND postid = :postid 
        ORDER BY commentid DESC";
```

I do simple.

```
$post_id = '1';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE postid = :postid";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(":postid", $post_id);
$stmt->execute();
$comment = $stmt->rowCount();
if($comment == 0){
    echo "be the first commenter";
}else{
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        //display your codes here
    }
}
```

**NOTE** : I am using `PDO` prepared statements, you need to do in mysqli